# Is Couchbase able to replicate only a specific subset of data to a specific node?

Tags: android, nosql, couchbase

I have the following usecase:

I want to use Couchbase on a server to store data, and use Couchbase for Android on mobile devices. I would like to use the Couchbase synchronisation to be able to work online and offline with the data and have it synced up eventually. But I don't want the different clients to sync all the data onto the device, just a specific subset. What subset a client should sync, should be controlled by the client, and should be changed dynamically.

Is Couchbase able to handle such a scenario? And if, could you give me some hints to the matching documentations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couchbase can not do this. More importantly I can't think of any solution that would. Couchbase is a clustered nosql solution. Others are caching solutions or databases. They store data. The logic of syncing the data between different stores and the syncing of sub-sets of data would have to be done within your application.

Comment: might it be possible by dynamically creating a couchbase bucket for each user within the application logic?

Comment: @mulllhausen You can't create that many Buckets, there are resources assigned to every Couchbase Bucket and at this point you can't have millions of them in a cluster.

Answer (score 0):

Sync Gateway now handles the logic permitting users access to channels, which then contain subsets of data based on which channel(s) each document belongs to.

http://docs.couchbase.com/sync-gateway/#channels